# Eliminating the word "Appendix"

Tags: appendices

I use the following command to add an appendix to my thesis:

`\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Some stuff here}
\section{Some other stuff here}`

Then I see the following.

[image]

I do not want the word "Appendix" at the bottom right corner. Then I change the code above to

`\appendix
\chapter{}
\section{Some stuff here}
\section{Some other stuff here}`

But this time the table of contents turns into this:

[image]

I still want the table of contents to say A. Appendix. How do I accomplish this?

Compilable code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,amsthm}                      
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                      
\usepackage{a4wide}                                         
\usepackage{placeins}                                       
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, caption, subfig}             
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}                          
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}                              
\usepackage{array,arydshln}                                 
\usepackage[british]{babel}                                
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}                                
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfborder=000]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib,enumerate}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{
  \thm@preskip=0.2cm plus 0cm minus 0cm
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother


\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}                        
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}                          

\pagestyle{fancy}                                  
\fancyhead{}                                       
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}                          
\fancyfoot[C]{\bf{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}               
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}               
\fancypagestyle{plain}{                            
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}                   
\fancyhead{}                                       
\fancyfoot[C]{}}                                  

\titlecontents{chapter}[0.7cm]                              
              {\vspace{-0cm}}                               
              {\bfseries\large\contentslabel{0.7cm}}                                                        
              {\bfseries\large\hspace{-0.7cm}}              
              {\titlerule*[2mm]{.}\bfseries\contentspage}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{5pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{5pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table Of Contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
Making the code compilable

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable code?

Comment: @Bernard I just did. Sorry that it is not minimal but I lost track of what each command is doing and whenever I take out something the compiler complains. I hope this is not too cluttered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way with `apptools`. I draw your attention to the fact that, according to the `l2tabu` guide, `a4wide` should not be used any more. If you want more sensible margins than the default, load `geometry`. Also `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions (most notable `cleveref`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{geometry} \usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, caption, subfig}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{array, arydshln}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{natbib,enumerate}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{
  \thm@preskip=0.2cm plus 0cm minus 0cm
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfborder=000]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\bf{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0.7cm]
              {\vspace{-0cm}}
              {\bfseries\large\contentslabel{0.7cm}}
              {\bfseries\large\hspace{-0.7cm}}
              {\titlerule*[2mm]{.}\bfseries\contentspage}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{5pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{5pt}
\usepackage{apptools}
\AtAppendix{\renewcommand\appendixname{\relax}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table Of Contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{A First Chapter}
\lipsum
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
Making the code compilable

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution and your other suggestions. Really appreciated.

Comment: B.t.w., I forgot to mention it, but you might want to replace `enumerate`  with `enumitem` which has the same functionalities as the former, but is much more powerful.